# Better way to INSERT/UPDATE a Customer table from a Key/Value style Property table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, dml

I have a customer master table called `Customer`. Everything in this table comes from a key/value style table called `Cust_Property`.

The `Cust_Property` table has 3 columns:

```
CustomerID, Property, Value
```

The `Property` column may contain `First_Name` with a value of `John`. Sort of like a pre-pivoted table. I need to update the columns in `Customer` table with the values of the associated `Property` columns in `Cust_Property` table.

**Rules**

- If there is a new `CustomerID` in the `Cust_Property` table, it will need to be added as a new row to the `Customer` table, as well as all appropriate properties.
- All data in the `Customer` table will also be in the `Cust_Property` table. That means that not every record needs to be updated. Only those that have changed or are new.
- Records are only added/updated in `Customer` table, not removed.
- There are properties in the `Property` table where a corresponding column doesn't exist in the `Customer` table, so those are just ignored.

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE #Customer
(
    Customerid int,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    Address1 varchar(100),
    Address2 varchar(100),
    Address3 varchar(100)
)

CREATE TABLE #Cust_Property
(
    CustomerID int,
    Property varchar(50),
    Value varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Customer (Customerid, FirstName, LastName, Address1, Address2, Address3) 
VALUES(1, N'John', N'Smith', N'123 happy lane', NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO #Customer (Customerid, FirstName, LastName, Address1, Address2, Address3)
VALUES(2, N'Dwight', N'Schrute', N'33 1st Ave', N'Apt 5', NULL);

INSERT INTO #Customer (Customerid, FirstName, LastName, Address1, Address2, Address3)
VALUES(3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);


INSERT INTO #Cust_Property (CustomerID, Property, Value)
VALUES(3, N'First_Name', N'Michael');

INSERT INTO #Cust_Property (CustomerID, Property, Value)
VALUES(3, N'Last_Name', N'Scott');

INSERT INTO #Cust_Property (CustomerID, Property, Value)
VALUES(8, N'First_Name', N'Jim');

INSERT INTO #Cust_Property (CustomerID, Property, Value)
VALUES(8, N'Last_Name', N'Halpert');

INSERT INTO #Cust_Property (CustomerID, Property, Value)
VALUES(8, N'Address1', N'644 Scranton Rd');

INSERT INTO #Cust_Property (CustomerID, Property, Value)
VALUES(8, N'Nickname', N'Jimmy');

INSERT INTO #Cust_Property (CustomerID, Property, Value)
VALUES(1, N'First_Name', N'John');
```

**Tables:**

`Customer`

| CustomerID | FirstName | LastName | Address1 | Address 2 | Address 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | 123 happy lane |  |  |
| 2 | Dwight | Schrute | 33 1st Ave | Apt 5 |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |

`Cust_Property`

| CustomerID | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | First_Name | Michael |
| 3 | Last_Name | Scott |
| 8 | First_Name | Jim |
| 8 | Last_Name | Halpert |
| 8 | Address1 | 644 Scranton Rd |
| 8 | Nickname | Jimmy |
| 1 | First_Name | John |

Desired `Customer` table end result:

- `Customer` 3's `First_Name` and `Last_Name` columns are updated
- Add customer 8 to `Customer` table b/c it doesn't already exist
- Update all of customer 8's properties except property `Nickname` because that doesn't exist in the `Customer` table
- Ignore the `First_Name` property for `CustomerID = 1` because it is the same in the `Customer` table, so no update needed.

My current method: first find and insert new `CustomerID`s

```
INSERT INTO #Customer (CustomerID)
    SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID 
    FROM #Cust_Property a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Customer x 
                      WHERE a.CustomerID = x.CustomerID)
```

Then update properties

```
 UPDATE #Customer
 SET #Customer.FirstName = a.Value
 FROM #Cust_Property a
 WHERE #Customer.CustomerID = a.CustomerID 
   AND a.Property = 'First_Name'

 UPDATE #Customer
 SET #Customer.LastName = a.Value
 FROM #Cust_Property a
 WHERE #Customer.CustomerID = a.CustomerID 
   AND a.Property = 'Last_Name'

 UPDATE #Customer
 SET #Customer.Address1 = a.Value
 FROM #Cust_Property a
 WHERE #Customer.CustomerID = a.CustomerID 
   AND a.Property = 'Address1'
    
 UPDATE #Customer
 SET #Customer.Address2 = a.Value
 FROM #Cust_Property a
 WHERE #Customer.CustomerID = a.CustomerID 
   AND a.Property = 'Address2'
    
 UPDATE #Customer
 SET #Customer.Address3 = a.Value
 FROM #Cust_Property a
 WHERE #Customer.CustomerID = a.CustomerID 
   AND a.Property = 'Address3'
```

In my actual tables, there are hundreds of different properties in `Cust_Properties` table, 40 columns in the `Customer` table that need updating and ~2M customer records.

Is there a better way that separate update statements for each? At present, I can't use an ETL tool, though I could technically use Python if that would be more efficient/faster.

Comment: This design violates [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) and [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and you're paying dearly for it. What is the purpose of the CustomerProperty table? If it's to store extra properties which are not Customer columns, could it be replaced with a single [JSON column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) on Customer?

Comment: @Schwern I would guess (hope??) that the EAV is just a staging table, which I suppose is maybe semi legit at a stretch. But even then, why not do the transform in the loading process? Maybe the OP can elaborate.

Comment: Trust me, I know this is terrible, but it's not my database and I'm not the DBA. I can't go into too much detail, but think of it as a customer's database that I have no power to make them change it. But what I am doing is grabbing their data (which lives in this Property table) and moving it into my Data Warehouse (Customer table) which utilizes Dimensional Modeling. So like @allmhuran said, I am pretending it is a staging table.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK, yea I know the INSERT could have been more concise. I Just quickly created these tables via DBeaver GUI and had it generate the DDL/DML for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe one update like -

```
UPDATE c
    set c.[FirstName] = isnull(cp.[First_Name],c.[FirstName])
    ,c.[LastName] = isnull(cp.[Last_Name],c.[FirstName])
    ,c.[Address1] = isnull(cp.[Address1],c.[Address1])
FROM #Customer c
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM #Cust_Property tb
        pivot(
            max(value)
            for Property in ( [First_Name],[Last_Name],[Address1],[Nickname])
            )pv
            )cp
    on c.Customerid = cp.CustomerID
```

Comment: Yea, Pivoting was another idea I had but wasn't sure where to implement. I'll give this a try.